# How can I send a region of the screen to a TV that is connected to HDMI port ? (by FFmpeg or C# codes or etc)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, c#

I need to send a region of the screen to a TV that is connected to HDMI port.

How can I do it?

Is it possible by FFmpeg or other tools? (Cheap commercial or free tools)

Comment: This question may be off-topic if you are asking for [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), which has its own Stack site. You could try some of the things listed here: http://vjforums.info/threads/need-software-to-duplicate-area-of-screen-on-second-monitor.11048/

Comment: My question is not on that list.

Comment: Did you try any of the solutions in the list though? Windows Magnifier or Ultramon software.

Comment: No I didn't , I think that is not what I need.